# Union type derived from keyof class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way in TypeScript to make a union type be a union of keys found in a class only?

For example, let `MyClass` be the following:

```
class MyClass {
  propertyA: string;
  propertyB: number;
  propertyC: number[];

  someMethod() {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Is there any way to tell TypeScript that I want a union type only from the properties of `MyClass`? So, something like

```
type MyType in keyof MyClass = "propertyA" | "propertyC";
```

This is invalid syntax, but this is the effect I'm looking for.

Also if I try

```
type MyType in keyof MyClass = "propertyA" | "propertyC" | "heyThere";
```

this would be an error, but the following

```
type MyType in keyof MyClass = "propertyA" | "propertyB" | "propertyC";
```

would not.

I lack formal vocabulary in TypeScript, so I'm not sure what might help here.

I've looked on here and online, but I've found different things than what I am looking for. For example, I've come across

```
type MyType = keyof MyClass;
```

but this gives me everything in `MyClass`.

Bonus: How can we tell TypeScript that a type we expect must be a union of strings?

I've also noticed if I use the `Pick` built in type, TypeScript correctly forces me to pick keys for that class, where as `Omit` built in type doesn't. This is why I am looking for this caveat.

Comment: For your "bonus", what do you mean by "must be union of strings"?  Certainly `"a" | "b"` is a union of strings, but what about just `"a"`?  Or `string` itself?  A [mcve] including things you'd like to accept and other things you'd like to reject would be helpful here.  And I'm thinking it might be a bit out of scope for the original question, depending on how you answer.

Comment: @jcalz For a union of strings I just mean something to the effect of `"a" | "b"`. I mean to say I want to expect to receive a union made of strings. It could be free of constraints or I can control where those strings come from, like a particular object or class property names. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: So, what about `"a"`?  Or `string` itself?  Do those count as "unions made of strings" or not?

Comment: The type `"a"` counts, but not `string`.

Comment: So does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPRbW) work for your needs?

Comment: @jcalz Perfect. That's exactly it. As you mentioned, I would also want to include the empty union. Thank you for your help on this, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in syntax that acts as you describe, but you can make a helper [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) like this:

```
type MustExtend<U, T extends U> = T;
```

And then instead of

```
// type MyType in keyof MyClass = "propertyA" | "propertyC";
```

You can write

```
type MyType = MustExtend<keyof MyClass, "propertyA" | "propertyB">; // okay
// type MyType = "propertyA" | "propertyB"
```

which works as desired.  And if you make a mistake, it warns you:

```
type MyType2 = 
  MustExtend<keyof MyClass, "propertyA" | "propertyC" | "heyThere">; // error!
// -----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"heyThere"' is not assignable to type 'keyof MyClass'.
```

also as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcB7XAU3wBd4BBAQgC5oJz8BLAOwHMBuLHA4spQBC9aGwCuAWwBGZHjjxFSFJKIkyyAbQC6PXtgiFJJWCXIALQgBMAFAEp0+hdAD0L6ABFCjI2fPsOJwBfDBCMSlI4cSYAUQAPchI2KwAeAFUAGmgAFWgSBKSrGDSAPmgAXhy9N2gIkjh4bPhI9mgAaxJ4QgAzBuRIGEqAIn5lSioh6AAfaBGlQSQhvTqGpsjK2GjyeMTklI6u3oR+qCy5gRUJ6dnRhaEhkq5Xd0I2sHgMGpWENfrh28ukxm5zG8HuGHCzXqPyhACYKlFYgU9gcen0UBAzgDxkCbvMVIhcUNzJ1siT8CQHk8amQiPgaJ93ABaFmstnsjmcrllAB+fP5AsFQuFIr5jJyUOgAHJiaTyZSpdAWDA2IRyNABiwOGwwNIQPVyN4VlLUUckBipQA6CEYIA)

Comment: Thank you for providing a good answer. This works as expected.